# Creating parallelogram with no right angles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, digitizing

I am trying to create a rhomboid, i.e. a four-sided polygon with two pairs of parallel sides but with no right angles. I know how to create rectangles using the Shape Digitizing Toolbar, but is there also a way to create a parallelogram with non-right angled corners?

I am using QGIS 3.14.16.

Answer (score 4):

1. You can use the <kbd>Shape Digitizing</kbd> toolbar to [draw a rectangle](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#draw-rectangles)
2. Select the [Vertex Tool](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html?#vertex-tool) and click on, for example, the top edge of your rectangle (not at the center as we don't want to create a new vertex) and slide your mouse up/down and left/right to create a rhomboid.

[image: demo gif]

*p.s.* : the QGIS links are for QGIS version 3.10 as the OP question is for 3.14

Comment: I have tried to follow your advice, but when using the Vertex tool, I only manage to move the vertices of my polygon around, without knowing if I am creating a true rhomboid. I can try to make it look like a rhomboid, but I don't know if the sides of my polygon are truly parallel. Did I miss something?

Comment: @Jama: I added a GIF for demo.

Comment: Now I got it. Thank you!

Comment: Please, @Jama then mark as accepted J. Monticolos answer.